# Programming best practice for PHP configuration class and dependent classes

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I have an opportunity to rewrite a very large PHP application I wrote a year ago and I'm looking for feedback on an idea I had for implementing the application configuration.

Currently I have a configuration class that reads my massive (and very human readable) `config.php` file that lets me access configuration parameters in the PHP code nicely and easily. This configuration object is instantiated as a variable in my `_init.php` script. A simplified sample is below:

```
<?php
  class Configuration {
    public $someConfigProperty = true;
    public const someOtherConstant = false;
  }

  // _init.php
  $CONFIGURATION = new Configuration;
?>
```

This works well, except that in every method of every other class I have to declare the `$CONFIGURATION` variable as a global. What I'd like to do instead is have every other class that needs to access the configuration object just extend the `Configuration` class. Something like this:

```
<?php
  class Configuration {
    public $someConfigProperty = 'some string';
    public const someOtherConstant = false;
  }

  class Foo extends Configuration {
    public static function getConfigProperty() {
      return $this->someConfigProperty;
    }
  }
?>
```

**My question is: is this a bad idea, and if so why? I'm looking for technical reasons why this shouldn't be done or concerns about future maintainability that would make this a bad idea.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this probably a bad idea. In general, classes that extend other classes imply a specialization relationship. Classic examples include `Cat extends Mammal` and `Square extends Rectangle`. In both cases, the former is a specialization of the latter. So unless `Foo` is a special kind of configuration, it should not extend `Configuration`.

What you want here is "Dependency Injection". Google it. Meanwhile, there are some nice PHP classes (like [this one](http://php-di.org/)) to give you instant injection, like this:

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct(Configuration $config) {
        echo $config->getConfigProperty();
    }
}
```

Like magic, the DI library makes that Configuration object available to you automatically, by the mere act of incorporating it in your signature.

Now, this is one way of doing DI. There are others. Google "php dependency injection" and you'll get a good idea of the different ways.

Answer (score 2):

I generally use a pattern like this, and have various configuration files, one for each Service. This example is for PostgreSQL:

**1. Prepare Individual Environment Files**

Have one file for each environment the application runs on, but name it something generic like `config.local.php`. Either have that file permanently emplaced on a server, or copied to the relevant location from an inaccessible environment folder to the regular config folder during deployment (using hooks / post-deplotment scripts, etc). The file format might look like this:

```
define("POSTGRESQL_DATABASE", "mydatabasename");
define("POSTGRESQL_USERNAME", "myusername");
define("POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD", "itsasecret");
define("POSTGRESQL_SERVER_IP", "localhost");
```

e.g. you might have a folder structure like this:

```
-config
-environments
  -test
    -config
  -prod
    -config
-public_html
```

...and copy the contents of `/environments/prod/config/` to `/config/` in a post-deployment hook.

Ideally, you would keep the configuration files out of your main source control, and instead create them individually on each server (perhaps copy them from a separate secure repository?)

This file would be included from `/config/` during your initialisation process.

**2. Create a Configuration Class that uses these Constants**

Create your configuration class which holds your configuration variables, with setters being private (and called in the constructor) and getters being public.

```
class PostgreSQLDatabaseConfiguration
{
    private $databaseName = null;
    private $password = null;
    private $serverIP = null;
    private $username = null;
    #endregion

    #region Public methods
    final public function __construct($serverIP, $databaseName, $username, $password) {
        $this
            ->setServerIP($serverIP)
            ->setDatabaseName($databaseName)
            ->setUsername($username)
            ->setPassword($password);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDatabaseName() {
        return $this->databaseName;
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getServerIP() {
        return $this->serverIP;
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private methods
    private function setDatabaseName($databaseName) {
        $this->databaseName = $databaseName;
        return $this;
    }

    private function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    private function setServerIP($serverIP) {
        $this->serverIP = $serverIP;
        return $this;
    }

    private function setUsername($username) {
        $this->username = $username;
        return $this;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**3. Have a Common Config File that generates your configuration class**

This file would be common to all environments (i.e. make up part of your standard deployment) and would instantiate a configuration object using the defined constants from the previous step:

```
include('/config/config.local.php');    
$postgresqlDatabaseConfiguration = new PostgreSQLDatabaseConfiguration(
    POSTGRESQL_SERVER_IP,
    POSTGRESQL_DATABASE,
    POSTGRESQL_USERNAME,
    POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD
);
```

Your configuration object is now ready to be injected into your DatabaseAccessor class, and your main code base is environment-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

No explanation why you need classes to propagate constants.
Using the defines in the application directly looks simpler to me.
For example:

```
PostgreSQLDatabaseConfiguration::getDatabaseName()
```

Could just as simply be referenced by its define:

```
POSTGRESQL_DATABASE
```

With the later method you only have to copy the file with defines to the target environment.
Programming is the art of keeping things as simple as possible.